# simplify Meijer's G in sympy

Tags: sympy, simplify

The Meijer's G function is a neat instrument to treat multiplication of random variables, and for a work I am conducting on this subject I am trying to use it in Sympy ( since it is not present in Sage or other free programs).
It looks that the "meijerg" packages available in Sympy provide a wide set of instruments
I succeeded to import it together with the relevant package for integrals ("sympy.integrals.meijerint") and could start and do some basic manipulations, like plotting, inverting argument (_flip_g), computing values, etc.
However, notwithstanding my best efforts, I cannot succeed and get Sympy to perform some of the most basic simplifications, for example the "absorbtion" of powers of the argument.
So after defining

```
b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5  = symbols('b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5')
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5  = symbols('a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5')
y,w,z =symbols('y w z',positive=True)
def G1(x):
    return(meijerg([[a1,a2,a3],[a4,a5]], [[b1,b2],[b3,b4]], x))
def G2(x):
    return(meijerg([[c1,c2],[c3]], [[d1,d2,d3],[d4]], x))
```

then asking the integral

```
Ris=_int0oo(G1(y*x),G2(w*x),x)
Ris
```

I get (on Jupyter)
[image: Int_G_1]
and no way to "absorb" the y at denominator.
Instead, if I input

```
integrate(G1(y*x)*G2(w*x),(x,0,oo))
```

I get
[image: Int_G_2]
and the first line is in fact what I would like to get.

So my question is why the absorbtion simplification is not attainable/ how can be attained with any of the instruments in the package (_rewrite1, _guess_expansion, etc.)

---- *addendum* ---
I realize from the comments that I fell into a newby trap: thanks indeed to Davide for signalling.
However, apart from and before  integrating, some basic algebraic manouvres on G like inverting the argument (the "hidden" tool  _flip_g), absorbing a power of the argument, rewriting a function as G, and alike, would be much useful.
Any way to properly access them ? if not, it would remain as a kind request to developers to render them utilizable. Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on the integral module, but I can tell you this. In Python development, any function starting with `_` (underscore) is meant to be a private function (meaning the final user shouldn't care about or use those functions). Instead, the final user should use all the functions starting with a character that is not an underscore! So, in the above example, you obtained the expected result when you used `integrate`, which is exposed by SymPy to the users (with `from sympy import *` or `import sympy as sp` and then `sp.integrate`)!

Comment: Differently, you had somehow imported all the functions of some integral sub-module, hence you imported `_int0oo` and other "underscored-functions". You are not meant to use them: they might change from version to version in order to implement new behaviors or functionalities. You should use `integrate`, which "hides" all the logic behind the different integral sub-modules. Somehow, `integrate` is going to use a correct sequence of "private" functions to compute an appropriate result.

Comment: @Davide_sd: thanks so much for signalling the .."trap". I added some lines on whether some basic simplifications are available apart from being executed within an integral. Can you please answer to that?

Comment: This seems a reasonable feature request but SO is not the place to make feature requests (they should go to github).